# How To Make a Map Center on User's Location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

How do I make a map center on the client's current location, but default to the LatLng below if the current location can't be determined.

```
var myOptions = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.659493, 79.415412),
  zoom: 12,
  scrollwheel: false,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the HTML 5 Geolocation functions for this purpose. It's close but not super precise.

[**Demo**](http://freezoo.alwaysdata.net/geoloc.html)

```
  var map;

  function initialize() {
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
      success = function(position) {
        createMap(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      };
      error = function() { createMap(12.659493, 79.415412); }

      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
    }
    else {
      createMap(12.659493, 79.415412);
    }
  }

  function createMap(lat, lng) {
    var mapOptions = { center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng), 
      zoom: 12,
      scrollwheel: false,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
  }
```